# Retrieve Subvolume ID and Name for BTRFS Root Subvolume in bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, arch-linux, btrfs

I'm designing a sophisticated ArchLinux script that will install ArchLinux and automatically configure the system for a proper install. The script can install BTRFS with subvolumes and configure SystemdBoot, which is the problem comes in.

Basically, I need to the script to be able to retrieve the root subvolume's ID and name in order for the script to properly configure SystemdBoot.

I already know what command I need to get this information, which is `btrfs su li /`. However, I would like to retrieve the values of the root subvolume only and save them as variables `RootSubvolID` and `RootSubvolName` respectively I can use it in my script at this line.

```
if [ "$use_btrfs" = "yes" ]; then
   root_flags="${root_flags} rootflags=subvolid=[RootSubvolID],subvol=[RootSubvolName]"
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can guarantee the name of the subvolume won't start with whitespace and won't contain newline characters, you could do:

```
if 
  name=$(
    LC_ALL=C btrfs sub show / |
      LC_ALL=C grep -aPom1 '^\s*Name:\s*\K\S.*'
  ) &&
    id=$(
      LC_ALL=C btrfs sub show / |
        LC_ALL=C grep -aPom1 '^\s*Subvolume ID:\s*\K\d+$'
    )
then
  do-something-with "$name" and "$id"
else
  echo >&2 "Can't determine name and/or id"
fi
```

For the subvolume ID, you could also use:

```
id=$(btrfs inspect-internal rootid /)
```

Which may be more reliable in the face of unusual subvol names.

Alternatively, you could get the information from the mount table, assuming the name doesn't contain `,` characters:

```
IFS=,
set -o noglob
for o in $(findmnt -no options -M /)
  case $o in
    subvolid=*) id=${o#*=};;
    subvol=*) name=${o#*=};;
  esac
done
```

Beware some characters in the name may be represented as `\xHH` sequences.

Comment: Yeah, subvolume names always start with @ with no whitespaces and no newline character names, and the root subvolume will always be called @

Comment: That's not true at all. While many installers default to adding @ to the subvolume name, it's definitely not mandatory. I only use the @ notation for subvolumes that have their own partitions (and are mounted via `/etc/fstab`); anything I create underneath is just a normal directory name.

Comment: @ajgringo619 I wasn't saying that all installers always start with @, I was saying that my script in particular always make the subvolumes start with @

Comment: @NovaLeary - OK, that makes sense.